# GCP IAMでAWS STSの様に一時ユーザcredentialsを発行したい

Tags: aws, security, google-cloud

お世話になります。

掲題の通りですが、クライアントアプリから直接GCPのサービスにアクセスするために、
AWS STSのgetFederationTokenの様なもので一時ユーザを発行することはできますでしょうか。

もしくは、それ以外にGCP固有のエンドユーザが直接GCPのAPIリクエストを行う際のセキュリティ的アプローチがあるようであれば、
そういったものでも問題無いと考えております。

もしご存知の方がおられましたら、ご教示いただけると幸いです。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。